# What's the difference between declaring an intent-filter in an activity vs. a receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I would like my application to be registered a handler for phone calls via the "Complete action using..." dialog. I've found that it works if I use the following syntax in my manifest:

```
   <activity android:name="my.class">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:scheme="tel" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

but if I register it as a broadcast receiver, my app doesn't show up in the "Complete action using..." dialog.

```
   <receiver android:name="my.class">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:scheme="tel" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

What's the difference between the two apart from the type of class that's going to be called  once an Intent matches the filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difference is clear: the first one will try to launch an `Activity`, while the second one will execute a `BroadcastReceiver`. What to use depends on what you want to achieve; use `BroadcastReceiver` when you want to catch some event but do not want to show anything to the user.

Comment: I understand the difference between an Activity and a BroadcastReceiver, but my question was regarding whether there are any differences in how the Android OS treats them. For example, it looks like only Activities appear in the OS defaults picker. Are there other such gotchas?